# Android:onKeyPreIme doesn't work when the soft keyboard pops up in Android14

Tags: android, android-14

I have a page with EditText,and I expect to exit both the soft keyboard and the page when I hit the system back key.
The way I handle it before is by overwriting EditText's onKeyPreIme method to listen to KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK 
But I recently discovered that on Android14, the onKeyPreIme method doesn't work when you use gesture navigation back with the soft keyboard still present

Is there any other way to fulfill my needs

Answer (score 0):

you can use any of the 3 methods below to solve your problem, whichever suits you best.

```
  override fun onBackPressed() {
        // Hide the edittext you 
        hideSoftKeyboard(edittext.windowToken)
        super.onBackPressed()
    }

   //  1-  To hide the keyboard you can do it with edittext (for one only edittext) token.
    private fun hideSoftKeyboard(windowsToken: IBinder) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowsToken, 0)
    }
     // 2-  If you are in actvity you can solve it like this
    private fun hideSoftKeyboard() {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this@YourActivity.window.decorView.windowToken, 0)
    }
     
     // 3- If you are in fragment you can solve it like this

      private fun hideSoftKeyboard() {
        val imm = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(requireActivity().window.decorView.windowToken, 0)
    }
```